# A question on IOCP

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, iocp

If I want to use completion port to get information from different thread ,

how can I design the structure of the program?How about the one below?

If I want to use a global function ,how can I set the mutexes ?

```
Main(){
  for i in range NumOfThreads{
    CreateIoCompletionPort() 
    CreatThread(ThreadFun)
  }
}

ThreadFun(){

    While(1){
      GetQueuedCompletionStatus(); // wait for completion of an IO
      Process What ever has completed ();
      Start another file operation();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
Main(){
  for i in range NumOfThreads{
    CreateIoCompletionPort() 
    CreateThread(ThreadFun)
  }

  for i in range NumOfCallerThreads
    CreateThread(ThreadCaller)
}

ThreadCaller(){
  While(1){
    Start another file operation();
  }
}


ThreadFun(){
    While(1){
      GetQueuedCompletionStatus(); // wait for completion of an IO
      Process What ever has completed ();
    }
}
```

You can do it without any critical sections! All you need is a guarantee that "Start another file operation();" will not be called after closing corresponding IOCP.

Answer (score 0):

Push Framework, http://www.pushframework.com uses this design too, except that it adds another thread to accept incoming connections.